# Control yticks using a mathematical formula

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I am trying to define the yticks using a mathematical function of `$ymin$` and `$ymax$`. Although the `$y_{min}$ $y_{max}$` are  known, I can't insert explicit values for yticks because I have to do this for more then 100 Subplot.

Here is a MWE using one subplot:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.2.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2013, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
% 
% 
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pgfplotsset{
  yticklabel style={text width=2em,align=right},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=0.782786366646341in,
height=0.587194955785812in,
scale only axis,
xmin=-359.244881781626,
xmax=360.065217547088,
xtick={\empty},
ymin=1.28609457650951,
ymax=1.41228987725779,
name=plot13,
label style={font=\large}, every axis/.append style={font=\large},mark size=0.05mm,xticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},ytick={\pgfkeysvalueof{(/pgfplots/ymin+/pgfplots/ymax)/2+(/pgfplots/ymax-/pgfplots/ymin)/3}},\pgfkeysvalueof{(/pgfplots/ymin+/pgfplots/ymax)/2},\pgfkeysvalueof{(/pgfplots/ymin+/pgfplots/ymax)/2-(/pgfplots/ymax-/pgfplots/ymin)/3}}}
]
\addplot[only marks,mark=o,color=red] plot coordinates{
(360.065217547088,1.39854349784227)
(-359.244881781626,1.39982093981607)
(-358.40443489089,1.40172293948734)
(-357.561892567634,1.40301454475056)
(-356.718610304702,1.40301454475056)
(-355.875655724595,1.40301454475056)
(319.221524968047,1.36667619074149)
(320.08970805058,1.36858934829893)
(320.957755672442,1.36304494596182)
(321.826459553688,1.36224724551416)
(322.694770827825,1.36524275455075)
(323.560805974673,1.36481645576931)
(324.425775701233,1.36314189168674)
(325.291672663171,1.36277512257593)
(326.158330953695,1.36287625187893)
(327.024339486036,1.36342938970337)
(327.887351626729,1.36398061366958)
(328.747322724523,1.36596188738228)
(329.606940469401,1.3650567860349)
(330.467046411872,1.36405256454973)
(331.327080302014,1.36384365149643)
(332.185530594617,1.36317683899384)
(348.364917468781,1.36811797091692)
(349.208781043468,1.36945708129693)
(350.054024232307,1.37302916477729)
(350.898631395933,1.37356863309838)
(351.7406957981,1.37457957525552)
(352.580820188072,1.37565278541448)
(353.41941849678,1.37618826330081)
(354.261104922223,1.37735567565605)
(355.102859230821,1.38079070690794)
(355.942327918808,1.38186307944567)
(356.779608020006,1.38641832021829)
(357.616505810991,1.39241054346529)
(358.455157096563,1.39680348485733)
(359.295973133871,1.39854349784227)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

which dosn't compile. Without the `ytick={\pgfkeysvalueof{(/pgfplots/ymin+/pgfplots/ymax)/2+(/pgfplots/ymax-/pgfplots/ymin)/3}},\pgfkeysvalueof{(/pgfplots/ymin+/pgfplots/ymax)/2},\pgfkeysvalueof{(/pgfplots/ymin+/pgfplots/ymax)/2-(/pgfplots/ymax-/pgfplots/ymin)/3}}}`, I get the following result:

[image]

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, but for me it is a bit unclear where the `ymin` and `ymax` values given to the `axis` environment are coming from. Are they already provided by `matlab2tikz` or have you added them by hand? (Just for the record: I don't have any clue about `matlab2tikz`.) Because when they are already provided by `matlab2tikz`, isn't it possible to calculate the desired tick positions in Matlab and provide these numbers directly as a list? (I don't think there is a way to calculate positions in the _value_ part of the key.)

Comment: Yes, they are provided by Matlab2tikz and it is easier to do it in Matlab. The issue is that, I have generated the file for a couple of months, and I don't have access to Matlab anymore. Thus, I have to do all manipulations using pgfplots

Comment: Assuming that you where some kind of student: Don't you have any contact to the institute any more to ask a former colleague if you can use his computer to make the manipulation or ask him to do it for you? Or couldn't you install the free trial of Matlab available at the website? I think this will be much easier.